# Spring data elasticsearch 4.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Issue after upgrading to spring boot 2.3 and spring data elasticsearch 4.0.9.
I have a document like this:

```
public class Entity implements Serializable {
    @Id private String id;
    private URL url;
    ...
}
```

Thi was working fine with spring data 3.0 with Jackson, but after upgrading to 4.0 Jackson is no longer available and now I'm getting an instantiation exception from spring failing to instantiate the URL object.

Exception:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate java.net.URL using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments 
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.readEntity(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.readMapValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:375)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.readValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:296)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$ElasticsearchPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:915)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.readProperties(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:253)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.readEntity(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.read(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:165)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.read(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractElasticsearchTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(AbstractElasticsearchTemplate.java:602)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.get(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.findById(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy176.findById(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy176.findById(Unknown Source)
    at com.callfire.starters.elasticsearch.starter.store.AbstractGenericElasticSearchMapStore.load(AbstractGenericElasticSearchMapStore.java:153)
    at com.callfire.starters.elasticsearch.starter.store.AbstractGenericElasticSearchMapStore.load(AbstractGenericElasticSearchMapStore.java:50)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapStoreWrapper.load(MapStoreWrapper.java:165)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.mapstore.writebehind.WriteBehindStore.load(WriteBehindStore.java:206)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.mapstore.writebehind.WriteBehindStore.load(WriteBehindStore.java:56)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.putIfAbsent(DefaultRecordStore.java:1004)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.PutIfAbsentOperation.run(PutIfAbsentOperation.java:36)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.call(Operation.java:170)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:210)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:199)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:147)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:125)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:110)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.net.URL]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.net.URL.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:146)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:62)
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.net.URL.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:139)
    ... 55 common frames omitted
```

Any ideas on resolution appreciated.

Comment: Entity has a constructor that looks like this:
`public Entity(String id, String url) {
    this.id = id;
    this.url = new URL(url); 
}`

Comment: What type has the `url` property in the Elasticsearch mapping, what does a call to /indexname/_mapping return?

And how are the URL properties stored in Elasticsearch itself? what does /indexname/_doc/id return for some document?

btw, 4.0 is out of maintenance and 4.1 will reach end of support next month.

Comment: There's no mapping for the url property in Elasticsearch mapping, but looking at the document returned from Elasticsearch it looks like this:
`
url":{"protocol":"http","host":"example.com","port":-1,"file":"/RU0dlxpOa8fFkvrpkWOtL1BwRa4LS36o46pCI67fyeMxjIOZgz","authority":"example.com","path":"/RU0dlxpOa8fFkvrpkWOtL1BwRa4LS36o46pCI67fyeMxjIOZgz","handler":{"_class":"sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler","proxyPort":-1}`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you might not have any constructor that instantiates with URL as a parameter.

In your case, the constructor should be like.

```
public Entity(URL url, ** **) {
    this.url = url;
    **;
    **;
}
```

Also, you can use Lombok to get constructor functionality with annotations like @NoArgsConstructor, @AllArgsConstructor, @Data just add this to your model class it will work.

Answer (score 0):

From the data that is in the index it looks like the URL was stored as a nested object `url` with the properties `protocol`, `host`, `port`, `file`, `authority`, `path`, `handler` (which itself is an object).

On reading Spring Data Elasticsearch tries to create an object of the class `URL` in order to set these properties on the object. But the `URL` class does not have a constructor to do this.

To read that in, you will need to define a custom converter that can read and write an URL to a `Document` object (which is basically a `Map<String, Object>` and register that converter (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.5/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model.conversions)

Answer (score 0):

Long story short. After checking data on an old existing index URL was stored as String there, probably Jackson HAL module. I was able to preserve the behavior by adding two converters.

```
    @ReadingConverter
public static class StringToUrlConverter implements Converter<String, URL> {
    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public URL convert(String url) {
        return new URL(url);
    }
}

@WritingConverter
public static class UrlToStringConverter implements Converter<URL, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(URL url) {
        return url.toString();
    }
}
```